# Can not start database with rails using rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I made the huge mistake of deleting a rails app with the plan to clone it from git. Now I am stuck not getting my server running using rails s.

I keep getting the following error and am not sure how to fix it.

```
Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/application.rb:18:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/local_env.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/application.rb:18:in `open'
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/application.rb:18:in `block in <class:Application>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:35:in `block in on_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `on_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:53:in `before_configuration'
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/application.rb:16:in `<class:Application>'
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:SSS>'
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:129:in `block in perform'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:126:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: do you use git?

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the stack trace, you are missing this file:

```
/Users/macuser/Desktop/Freelance1/config/local_env.yml
```

It's a common pattern to avoid tracking some files with git. For example, `database.yml` or `secrets.yml`. This files are usually added to `.gitignore` to keep you credentials, another confidential data or just a local settings, that are useless for another team members, private.

That's why there are example-files, such as `database.example.yml` or `secrets.sample.yml` that usually have a fields that need to be filled in private files.

`local_env.yml` is usually used to set some environment variables for your application ([here](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) is an article about it). I think, there is something like this in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end
end
```

So it's trying to open file that doesn't exist and you get this error.

Check your project, maybe there is an example-file for `local_env.yml`. If there is no such file, you can change env-file loading like this:

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

So it will check if `config/local_env.yml` exists before trying to open it.

Or you can simply add a `config/local_env.yml` file.

But if you've had some important env-variables in this file, you probably will get errors in places where they are used. But I don't think that it will be a problem to locate this places (at least you can search for `ENV` across your project to check where env-variables are used) and add required variables to the `local_env.yml`.